# Inequality related the product/division of norms and the addition/subtraction of norms

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Given a set of three matrices $A, B, C$ of the same size.

I was wondering if there is then an inequality relating the following two series:

$S_1 = \lVert A \rVert^2_2 - \lVert C \rVert_2^{2} + \lVert B \rVert_2^2$

$S_2 = \frac{\lVert A \rVert_2^2 \cdot \lVert B \rVert_2^2}{ \lVert C \rVert_2^2}$

With the conditions that $tr(A)=tr(B)=tr(C)=1$